# Is it possible to update the Service Fabric Cluster Manifest?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I found the following API

`await fabricClient.ClusterManager.ProvisionFabricAsync(null, "testMani.xml");`

but have not figured out where to store the new manifest.xml file?

using it as listed here it will throw exception that the file testMani.xml do not exist in the store.

How can one after deployment manipulate the cluster manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cluster manifest and APIs that reference it are artifacts of Service Fabric's internal usage at Microsoft. Manipulating the manifest is not recommended nor supported.

For Azure deployments, you should make all changes to your cluster through an ARM template. For local development, the cluster configuration is currently fixed but we will eventually support additional flexibility there as well so that you can make your onebox look more like your real environment, especially for concepts like placement constraints. In that case, the cluster definition will likely take the same form as we'll use for [on-premise deployments](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-deploy-anywhere/).

Comment: Thanks Sean. I am also going through the arm provider right now. but it is limited in sense of what is possible to do after the initial cluster has been deployed. Let me know if you want feedback on email.

Comment: I actually posted some of my findings here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867851/how-to-update-the-nodetypes-of-service-fabric-after-deployment

Comment: Is it possible to edit the Cluster manifest at this point for local single box development?

Comment: Hi Dan, did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Maybe firewall, try connecting to the cluster from powershell like described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ncdevguy/2016/12/25/connecting-to-a-remote-azure-service-fabric-cluster-using-powershell/