# How to update the nodetypes of service fabric after deployment

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is there any way to update the nodetypes of a service fabric cluster after deployment?

I want to dynamicly add a new vm scaleset to the cluster, but if I cannot add a new node type in the service fabric cluster - then its not possible to create new placement constrains for this new vm scaleset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found no way using the newest ARM service fabric provider. But using an older one, it is possible.

`armclient put /subscriptions/8393a037-5d39-462d-a583-09915b4493df/resourceGroups/ServiceFabricTest3/providers/Microsoft.ServiceFabric/clusters/pksservicefabric?api-version=2015-01-01-alpha @test.json`

a few things that I learned was, that the below test.json file has to have

- its managementEndpoint given
- expectedVmResources should only have its primary node given.
- that one cannot provide instance count.

This leads me to believe that the ARM provider has some way to go.

```
{
  "location": "West Europe",
  "properties": {
    "managementEndpoint": "https://pksservicefabric.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19080",
    "certificate": {
      "thumbprint": "4B729ADE19BF2742BB09BB257C6BD8538DBDB1A4",
      "x509StoreName": "My"
    },
    "nodeTypes": [
      {
        "name": "nt1vm",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": true
      },
      {
        "name": "nt2vm",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      },
      {
        "name": "nt3vm",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      },
      {
        "name": "algorithm-a0",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      },
      {
        "name": "algorithm-a1",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      },
      {
        "name": "algorithm-a2",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      },
      {
        "name": "algorithm-a3",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      },
      {
        "name": "algorithm-a4",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      },
      {
        "name": "algorithm-a5",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      },
      {
        "name": "algorithm-a6",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": 19000,
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": 19080,
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": 20000,
          "endPort": 30000
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": 49152,
          "endPort": 65534
        },
        "isPrimary": false
      }
    ],
    "expectedVmResources": [
      {
        "name": "nt1vm",
        "nodeTypeRef": "nt1vm",
        "vmInstanceCount": 5,
        "isVmss": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```