# Set MaxOperationTimeout on cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell

I have a large package that I'm trying to deploy to a test cluster in Azure. I get an OperationTimeout when I'm trying to register the application type, so I figured I could send in the TimeoutSec parameter to Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType, but I'm getting an error back saying my value (1 hour) is greater than the MaxOperationTimeout configured on the cluster. Where would I configure this value, I can't find it anywhere? The package works locally.

```
Copying application to image store...
Copy application package succeeded
Registering application type... 
Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType : Client timeout must be less than or equal to the cluster configuration forMaxOperationTimeout. Requested value and timeout limit: (59:59.999, 10:00.000)
At D:\sf\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication2.psm1:220 char:9
+         Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationPathInImageStore $appl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType], FabricException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RegisterApplicationTypeErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.RegisterApplicationType
```

Comment: It turns out that it was related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119341/register-servicefabricapplicationtype-on-a-secure-cluster-always-times-out/38151560#38151560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the cluster manifest for an Azure cluster. As stated here: [Is it possible to update the Service Fabric Cluster Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830791/is-it-possible-to-update-the-service-fabric-cluster-manifest)

Comment: But I could re-deploy it right? Like if I wanted to go from 3 to 5 nodes for example. Or if I wanted to set this setting on a completely new cluster.

Comment: Changing the settings is not supported. Changing your node count should be done using an ARM template. (shown here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype-wad)